# MATLAB ConnectedComponentLabeler does not work in for loop

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to get a set of binary images' eccentricity and solidity values using the `regionprops` function. I obtain the label matrix using the `vision.ConnectedComponentLabeler` function.

This is the code I have so far:

```
files = getFiles('images');
ecc = zeros(length(files)); %eccentricity values
sol = zeros(length(files)); %solidity values

ccl = vision.ConnectedComponentLabeler;

for i=1:length(files)
 
    I = imread(files{i});
    
    [L NUM] = step(ccl, I);


    for j=1:NUM
      L = changem(L==j, 1, j); %*
    end

    stats = regionprops(L, 'all');

    ecc(i) = stats.Eccentricity;
    sol(i) = stats.Solidity;

end
```

However, when I run this, I get an error says indicating the line marked with *:

> Error using ConnectedComponentLabeler/step
>
> Variable-size input signals are not supported when the OutputDataType property is set to 'Automatic'.'

I do not understand what MATLAB is talking about and I do not have any idea about how to get rid of it.

## Edit

I have returned back to `bwlabel` function and have no problems now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit hard to understand, but I can explain what exactly it means.  When you use the CVST Connected Components Labeller, it assumes that all of your images that you're going to use with the function **are all the same size**.  That error happens because it looks like the images aren't... hence the notion about "Variable-size input signals".

The "`Automatic`" property means that the output data type of the images are automatic, meaning that you don't have to worry about whether the data type of the output is `uint8`, `uint16`, etc.  If you want to remove this error, you need to manually set the output data type of the images produced by this labeller, or the `OutputDataType` property to be static.  Hopefully, the images in the directory you're reading are all the same data type, so override this field to be a data type that this function accepts.  The available types are `uint8`, `uint16` and `uint32`.  Therefore, assuming your images were `uint8` for example, do this before you run your loop:

```
ccl = vision.ConnectedComponentLabeler;
ccl.OutputDataType = 'uint8';
```

Now run your code, and it should work.  Bear in mind that the input **needs to be `logical`** for this to have any meaningful output.

## Minor comment

Why are you using the CVST Connected Component Labeller when the Image Processing Toolbox `bwlabel` function works exactly the same way?  As you are using `regionprops`, you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, so this should be available to you.  It's much simpler to use and requires no setup: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html

Comment: another question waits for you (:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824984/matlab-how-to-calculate-elongation-of-a-bw-image