# MATLAB how to calculate elongation of a BW image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, topology

I am trying to extract features for a leaf recognition application in MATLAB. I need to get **elongation** value which is described as the following:

> Compute the maximum escape distance *d<sub>max</sub> = max<sub>X ∈ I</sub> d(X,∂I)*. Elongation is obtained as *1 - 2d<sub>max</sub> / D(I)* and ranges from 0 to 1. The minimum is achieved for a circular region. Note that the ratio 2d<sub>max</sub>/D(I) is the quotient between the diameter of the largest inscribed circle and the diameter of the smallest circumscribed circle.

**D(I)** is the diameter of the image **I**. **∂I** is border of **I**.

Pretend a circular shaped image. The furthest point to the border of this shape is the center. This is called as **maximum escape distance**.

```
Elongation = 1 - (interior ellipse radius/surrounding ellipse raidus)
```

[image]

regionprops result for the image is below:

```
 Area: 352085
 Centroid: [311.2075 492.9844]
 BoundingBox: [2.5000 2.5000 586 1139]
 SubarrayIdx: {1x2 cell}
 MajorAxisLength: 869.2058
 MinorAxisLength: 535.2340
 Eccentricity: 0.7879
 Orientation: -85.2073
 ConvexHull: [99x2 double]
 ConvexImage: [1139x586 logical]
 ConvexArea: 403293
 Image: [1139x586 logical]
 FilledImage: [1139x586 logical]
 FilledArea: 352085
 EulerNumber: 1
 Extrema: [8x2 double]
 EquivDiameter: 669.5435
 Solidity: 0.8730
 Extent: 0.5275
 PixelIdxList: [352085x1 double]
 PixelList: [352085x2 double]
 Perimeter: 3.2466e+03
```

Comment: What is the definition of the maximum escape distance?  Can you provide a numerical / visual / definition of this?  Can you also provide definitions on the other terms as well as a visual example?  It's hard to visualize all of this without an example image of what you're working on.

Comment: Can you provide a real example image of what you're dealing with?  Also, are you given anything else other than the "diameter" of the image?  What about the centre of the shape?

Comment: @rayryeng I have editted the question.

Comment: From the definition, it looks like the maximum escape distance is the max distance from a point in the image to its border. You can get this distance by taking the [distance transform](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) of the image and then taking its max value. If you are using the given image, you have to invert it and get the distance transform.